# Assign dynamic rows to Listbox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have dynamic rows on Column "A" on "Sheet1" which are changing time to time from 10 to 60 rows. I have this code to populate these rows into my Userform Listbox with option selection(when working in "Sheet 2"). I can not figure out where is the issue? :(

2) I will be most appreciate if let me know : how can I hide Columns that on Row "B" on "Sheet 2" have corespondent selected item from my listbox?
Below are screenshots:

[Q1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdevm.png) [Q2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFVjr.png)

Hope that make sense.
Thanks

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ColCnt As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ColWidths As String
    Dim i As Long


    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = Range("A1", .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    End With

        With Me.lbxRange
        .ColumnCount = 1
        .RowSource = rng.Offset(5).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Address
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Q1: It means the cells are not blank really. Either they are having white-space character or formula. Can you check and confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

In design mode, **clear** the **RowSource** property of the ListBox and give following code a try...

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, LR As Long
    Dim x()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To LR
            If VBA.Trim(.Cells(i, 1)) Like "?*" Then
                j = j + 1
                ReDim Preserve x(1 To j)
                x(j) = .Cells(i, 1)
            End If
        Next i
        If j > 0 Then
        Me.lbxRange.List = x
        Else
        Me.lbxRange.Clear
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Deleted unused variables, add them if they are used later in the same event.

Comment: Here is the code I tried to quick to suit my need from here. As the code show, it selects all rows and columns that have value in them. I only want Colum A in Sheet 1 to populate my listbox then hide correspondent columns.

Comment: Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ColCnt As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ColWidths As String
    Dim i As Long

    ColCnt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    With Me.lbxRange

        .ColumnCount = ColCnt
        .RowSource = _
            rng.Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Address
        For i = 1 To .ColumnCount

            ColWidths = ColWidths & rng.Columns(i).Width &";"
        Next i
        .ColumnWidths = ColWidths
        .ListIndex = 0
    End With
End Sub

Comment: @stkneer: when I run your macro I get Run-time error '9' ...Subscript out of range

Comment: Error 9 means, the object you are referencing is not available, look for the objects used in the line which produces that error.

Comment: @stkneer: Thanks :)

Comment: @Matt You're welcome! If this takes care of your original question, please take a minute to accept the answer to mark your question Solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

@stkneer: honestly I couldn't work it out to debug it. Here is a code that I came up for my first query and working properly. For the second query(hide column) i post it in new thread. Again Thanks

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim r As Range
    Dim DataArea As Range
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("a2").Select
    Set DataArea = Range("a2", Range("a2").End(xlDown))

     For Each r In DataArea
        lstBox1.AddItem r.Value
    Next r

    lstBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
    lstBox1.ListStyle = fmListStyleOption

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```